# Google Maps, marker info window won't show up?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have written this code that loops through an array of lat/long coordinates and places a marker at each of the coordinate. Everything forks fine, exempt the info window won't appear once the marker is clicked.

```
var ExpTowerIcon = new GIcon(); 
    ExpTowerIcon.image = "tower.png";
    ExpTowerIcon.iconSize = new GSize(75, 75);
    ExpTowerIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(37, 65);
    ExpTowerIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(37, 20);


var marker=new Array();

for ( i=0 ; i < lat.length  ; i++ ) {

    var MarkerPoint = new GLatLng(lat[i],long[i]); 
    marker[i] = new GMarker(MarkerPoint,{icon:ExpTowerIcon}) 
    map.addOverlay( marker[i] );

    GEvent.addListener( marker[i] , 'click', function() { marker[i].openInfoWindowHtml('Hello!') ; });

    var polyline = new GPolyline([ new GLatLng(lat[i],long[i]) , new GLatLng(lat[i+1],long[i+1]) ], "#ff0000", 5);
    map.addOverlay(polyline);

    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click handler:

```
function() { window['marker'+i].openInfoWindowHtml('Hello!') ; }
```

references the (global) variable i, which will be set to lat.length when the for loop exits.

I suggest:

```
function() { this.openInfoWindowHtml('Hello!') ; }
```

**Edit:**

If you need to have the marker number inside the click event handler, I suggest:

```
function getHandler(i) {
    return function () { this.openInfoWindow('tower' + i) ; };
}

for (i = 0; i < lat.length; i++) {
    ...
    GEvent.addListener( marker[i] , 'click', getHandler(i));
    ...
}
```

This binds the variable i to the click handler (the handler is now a *closure*). For more on closures, see [Working with Closures - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures)

Comment: Partly works, now all the markers have infowindows, but...
I have used this function
     GEvent.addListener( marker[i] , 'click', function() { this.openInfoWindow( 'tower'+i ) ; });
and it would tag all markers as 'tower6', rather then its current number in the array.